# Convert String to Date

Tags: java, string, date

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion) and its answers, I tried to convert string to date. But it seems to strange with me.

```
String test = "2015/01/01 11:56:00 ";
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");      
System.out.println(df.parse(test));
```

It returns

```
Mon Dec 29 11:56:00 ICT 2014
```

I have tried with other days but the results is not in the rule (i.e.  it have the same distance from the input string and the output date). I am curious. Can anyone explain this for me?

Comment: @Micho `parse` does not take `Date` object as a param.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all its yyyy not YYYY for year and try the below code to create a Date object from a String.

```
String test = "2015/01/01 11:56:00 ";
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = df.parse(test);
System.out.println(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

The date format is case-sensitive and therefore the parsing is evaluated differently from what you expected.

Try this:

```
String test = "2015/01/01 11:56:00 ";
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(df.parse(test));
```

Comment: `Date date = new Date("Nov 26 2015 00:00:00");` is superfluous. Dare to explain why `YYYY` doesn't work as expected?

Comment: The pattern is wrong. For month it should be MM not mm. mm is for minutes.